# Change numerical value into NA based on NA´s in other column

Tags: replace, na

Here is my dataset:

head(example)

```
 A1       A2       A3       B1      B2       B3
     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1  NA      -0.0255  -0.0179  -0.0801  -0.0203 -0.00506
2  0.0394  -0.00347 -0.124    0.0149   0.0317  0.0379 
3 -0.0202   0.00918 -0.00906  0.00994  0.0255  0.0365 
4  NA      -0.0359  -0.0307   0.00471  0.0145  0.0209 
5 -0.00246 -0.0432. -0.00114  0.151    0.0978  0.0784 
6 -0.0446  -0.196   -0.146    0.0316   0.0320  0.0322
```

I want to compare A1, with B1, A2 with B2 and A3 with B3, but want to replace the values on row 1 and 4 in B1 with NA, since A1 has NA on row 1 and 4.

I havre tried this, but it does not work:

> eksempel$A1[eksempel$A1 > 0 & is.na(eksempel$B1)] <- NA
> eksempel$A1[eksempel$A1 < 0 & is.na(eksempel$B1)] <- NA